# Updating a different record every cycle using a for loop

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I have written a php code that generates many "secret_key". The code is below

```
 <?php

    include("/home3/kintest2/public_html/include/config.local.php");
    $connect= mysql_connect ($DBHOST,$DBUSER,$DBPASSWORD);
    $select= mysql_select_db($DBNAME, $connect);



    $test2= "SELECT *  FROM `video` WHERE `type` LIKE 'private'";
    $results= mysql_query($test2, $connect);
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($results);


    for ($count=$num_rows; $count>=0; $count-- && $secret_key= uniqid().mt_rand(1,9) )
    {
    mysql_query("UPDATE video SET secret_key= '$secret_key' WHERE type='private'",$connect);
    echo "    count is  {$count}  key is  {$secret_key}</br>";

    }
    ?>
```

I only have one problem with this code. All of the mysql records that satisfy the query conditions are given the same secret key. But I want the a different key to be assign to each record. 
`mysql_query("UPDATE video SET secret_key= '$secret_key' WHERE type='private'",$connect);`

This is the echo output

- count is 13 key is
- count is 12 key is 50090128c89bb7
- count is 11 key is 50090128c91153
- count is 10 key is 50090128c986c4
- count is 9 key is 50090128c9f9b5
- count is 8 key is 50090128ca7387
- ....

There ere 13 records in total.

Answer (score 0):

Your echo output already lists up different keys but even though I'd write the code a bit different:

```
while( !is_null($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) ) { 
  $secret_key=uniqid().mt_rand(1,9); /* (?) */ 
  $dbCmd = "UPDATE video SET secret_key = '$secret_key' WHERE id={$row['id']}";   
  msyql_query($dbCmd, $connect); 
}
```

Your Query does an update for EACH row with type='private' (atm) ...

Comment: The problem is that when I run the code below it makes all the records have the same secret key.      `mysql_query("UPDATE video SET secret_key= '$secret_key' WHERE type='private'",$connect);`

Comment: it gives me some error on this line. `$dbCmd = "UPDATE video SET secret_key = '$secret_key' WHERE id="{$row['id']}"; ` Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{'

Answer (score 0):

If you want the key to apply to only one row, you must tailor your `UPDATE` statement to affect *one row only.* So one approach is fetching some unique keys identifying the rows, and issuing a separate update query for each of them. Another alternative might be generating the random keys server-side using SQL.

Comment: @CongoleseMedia: I don't know your database, so I don't know what identifies a row. Frosti has already given you some details on that approach. `SET secret_key = LEFT(MD5(RAND()), 16)` or similar might work well enough for the loopless server-side approach.